# Why isn't GridLayout (Android) filling the screen?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to build a checkers-like (not actually checkers) android app, but I'm having a problem creating the initial board layout. I have all the java code for the game itself, but I need to now 'sync it up' with the android environment.

I'm using a GridLayout because my game is based on a 2D array, and I thought it would be easiest to map each cell in my game's array to a grid.

My XML for a 4x8 table is the following:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/Beige"

    android:useDefaultMargins="true"

    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="8"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.example.saltpepper.PlayTogetherActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
        <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
        <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
        <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
        <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
        <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
        <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/Beige"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

But for some reason its snapping the entire table to the top left of the screen, so there's extraneous blank space, as you can see:
[image: screenshot]

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: vote down due to unresponsiveness from you regarding your posted question since 12+ hours.